# Material-UI dark opacity background image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styles

I'm wrapping all the widgets in a CardMedia component, and setting an image.

```
return (
<CardMedia image={bg} className={classes.bg}>
  <main className={classes.content}>
    <div className={classes.toolbar} />

    <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6}>
          <Product product={product}></Product>
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  </main>
</CardMedia>);
```

I need to make the image a little darker.

Here is the code for the styles:

```
export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    /* backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default, */
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    [theme.breakpoints.down("lg")]: {
      paddingRight: 200,
      paddingLeft: 200,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xl")]: {
      paddingRight: 200,
      paddingLeft: 200,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
  },
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  bg: {
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
  },
}));
```

Maybe there is even a simpler way to create a background image with a darker tint?
Also, I don't know if this has to do with anything, but when I set the image with CardMedia, every time I scroll to the bottom of the page there is a short annoying lag. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should try to use this for made your image darker is a simple CSS function :

```css
 .img { filter: “brightness(50%)”; }
```

Also change your component if you not rendering any childrens inside :

```
 <Product><\Product>
```

to

```
 <Product />
```